# How to create a moving robot

Tags: gazebo, teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to create a moving robot but i don't know how i can do it. I tryed to di that learning driffdrive_plugin.cpp, but i don't understand how it is work.
There isn't main() function in this file, ROS doesn't need main() function? what ROS needs to controll joints by keyboard?

thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11897/how-to-create-a-moving-robot./) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2011-11-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on 2011-11-11**:
you should start with the tutorials, it will be easier than understand the whole system by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [erratic_description](http://www.ros.org/wiki/erratic_description) package is a good and complete example for a moving mobile base using the DiffDrivePlugin as a gazebo controller. Especially in `urdf/erratic_base.xacro` you can see how to use the plugin in your urdf model.

To see a running example run:

```
roslaunch erratic_description erratic_empty_world.launch
```

This starts gazebo and spawns the erratic model. Then run

```
rosrun erratic_teleop erratic_keyboard_teleop
```

You can now move the robot using the keys WASD.

---

Originally posted by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) with karma: 285 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on 2011-11-30**:
you can also use shift + WASD for speed up!